# Parsing large character fields using GSON

Tags: gson, rally

I was trying to parse a JSON object using GSON parser and write into database using JDBC. However some of the fields are quite large to store in string datatype after I parse them using GSON parser, and also creates a problem as I would have to increase my column size in database for storing larger strings.

My class structure looks similar to this:

public class Results {

```
public String _refObjectUUID;
public String _refObjectName;
public String _type;
public String _CreatedAt;
public String Description;
public String Notes;
public String Theme;
public String StartDate;
public String EndDate;
public String State;
public String PlannedVelocity;
public String FormattedID;
public Owner Owner;
public Project Project;
public String ScheduleState;
public String Ready;
public Release Release;
```

}

While parsing by using the above class, some of the fields like Description for example are quite large and variable in length. So I wanted to how GSON would support such large string? Is there something similar to CLOB datatype that GSON supports?